# Camel SCP warnings not handled correctly?

Tags: apache-camel

If I try to transfer a file to a directory that does not exist using Camel SCP I see a warning like this in the log:

```
[scp] WARN scp: /home/user/scp/1234: No such file or directory
```

It looks like the code says that Camel will just log a warning when such an error occurs.  There is no exception in the code, so it looks like the file was transferred when it was not.

[Caml SCP Code](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/52a739feb9da8acd29067304c7c8356bbc5ef4dd/components/camel-jsch/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/scp/ScpOperations.java#L347)

Shouldn't this be an error and an exception?  Or is there another way of doing the error handling here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Camel.  See the discussion on the Camel mailing list here.

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Camel-SCP-Warnings-tc5792552.html